# Linearity of complex-valued function from application of Liouville theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am trying on problems from Bak and Newman's complex analysis. On the part of regarding Liouville's theorem, there were quite a number of problems concerns and an inequality and then ask you to prove that the complex-valued function is a linear one. An example is the following:

Suppose $f$ is entire and $|f(z)|\leq A+B|z|^{3/2}$ for constants $A,B$. Show that $f$ is a linear polynomial.

I hope someone can solve one of them for me. It will be helpful for me to understand problems of similar type once I understand this one!

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2000145/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cf(z)%7C%5Cleq%20A%2BB%7Cz%7C%5E%7B3%2F2%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Yes, they do! Thanks for that